# Derivative of a specific function

Tags: derivatives

I'm having trouble evaluating the following expression and would appreciate anyone being able to step me through the process: [image: equation]

I'm a second-time poster so any suggestions for title/question rephrasing are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Your placement of the "$-1$" suggests you want $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{1}{c(t) \mathrm{e}^{-\rho t}}$.  Is that your intent?

Comment: Also, "solving" is a process applied to equations.  You haven't provided an equation.  You have provided an expression.  Are you having trouble *evaluating* that expression?

Comment: Yes to both your corrections. I'll try and edit the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the many case where logarithmic differentiation makes life easier$$y(t)=\frac{1}{c(t)\, {e}^{-\rho t}}\implies \log(y(t))=-\log(c(t))+\rho t$$
$$\frac{y'(t)}{y(t)}=-\frac{c'(t)}{c(t)}+\rho$$ Now, use
$$y'(t)=y(t)\times \frac{y'(t)}{y(t)}$$ and simplify.